# Powershell - adding a cmdlet without visual studio

Tags: c#, powershell, csc, powershell-cmdlet

I've downloaded a real nice cmdlet from this site, and would like to start using it.  I'm having difficulty understanding the process, if someone could kindly give a general overview.
I have the cmdlet already, i'm not sure if it needs further editing done.
Next, I register it with Powershell?  This is where i'm getting hung up, the tutorials i've found on this subject only mention using Visual Studio, which I don't have access to.
Also, where does this physical cmdlet (.cs) file get placed?
I think I will need some way to reference the system.management.automation.dll, at the very least.  I've created a Powershell profile, and would like to use this as much as possible.
Any other steps are much appreciated!

Comment: you can use VS Express edition to build DLL for cmdlets.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can compile the code and output an assembly or even an load the cs file at run time using the `Add-Type` cmdlet, no VS necessary.

I wrote an article that shows how you can do that over at PowerShellMagazine.com.

http://www.powershellmagazine.com/2013/05/13/measuring-powershell-scripts/

Comment: That is an excellent writeup, but I am still having trouble understanding building a snap-in in order to use register and use a new cmdlet.  I'll admit, i'm pretty new to this.

Comment: Okay, I think I should be able to create a module using Add-Type; How do I create a module composed of a couple .CS files that also need to reference a couple .DLL files though?

Comment: Check the examples of Add-Type, -UsingNamespace, -ReferencedAssemblies etc